# UILable (NSTextAlignmentCenter) substring frame

Tags: ios, objective-c

Задача такая: как вычислить frame подстроки (есть NSRange) у UILabel когда текст выровнен по центру - NSTextAlignmentCenter?

т.е позиция по origin - x, y и размер - wight, height.

Все работает хорошо, когда мы используем классы TextKit (NSTextStorage, NSLayoutManager, NSTextContainer) c использованием метода: `boundingRectForGlyphRange:inTextContainer:`, но с выравниванием по центру не работает.

Есть ли изящное решение для UILabel? или если нет, то как вычислять то же самое в UITextView?

Спасибо.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Я так понял, ты можешь узнать frame подстроки при выравнивании по левому краю, да? В таком случае можно из ширины textView вычесть ширину всей строки и разделить на 2. Это будет смещением слева, на него нужно будет увеличить frame.origin.x.